# Python - Predicting football matches

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting, poisson

I am fairly new to python and pandas, and I still struggle a lot. The course I am attending gave me a task that seems impossible for me, I hope someone can help me out.

I have a dataframe (simplified, it contains the whole season 16 results):

```
    season   date        team1          team2                score1   score2   result
12  2016    2016-08-13  Hull City       Leicester City       2.0    1.0        team1_win
13  2016    2016-08-13  Arsenal         Swansea City         0.0    1.0        team2_win
14  2016    2016-08-13  Southampton     Manchester Utd       1.0    1.0        draw
15  2016    2016-08-13  Middlesbrough   Stoke City           1.0    1.0        draw
16  2016    2016-08-13  Crystal Palace  West Bromwich Albion 0.0    1.0        team2_win
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Now, I would like to predict, how many goals each Arsenal and Manchester is going to score on the last season game Arsenal-Manchester. (It will probably not work with the part-data I gave here) This is to be done with a count regression.

I tried using the code I got from another example, but failed miserably:

```
modelArs = smf.poisson("score1 ~ score2 + team2", data=train_data)
resultArs = modelManc.fit();
```

And I know that this is probably total bs I did there, but I am just completely lost.

The second task is to display which team is going to win, based on a decision tree.

The third task is to use a mnlogit regression to display the probability of a draw, and a win for each team.

I know I am asking for a lot, but any help helps me a lot. Also including some information on what you actually did would help me. I am just trying to somehow pass the course, and be done with python afterward.

Answer (score 0):

first u need to hot en code categorical variables such as team1, team2, result
hot encoding is nothing but converting independent variables with limited possible values into numerical form.

refer to this link for knowing how hot encoding works:[Hot encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-hot-encoding-for-categorical-data/#:%7E:text=Machine%20learning%20models%20require%20all,and%20a%20One%2DHot%20Encoding.)

In this data some variables seems useless such as scores because you wont have access to scores when you want predictions so they can be omitted. And this model can be trained for learning purpose but it wont be efficient with this many few attributes as result of a game doesn't purely depend on attributes like [season,date,team1,team2] there are many factors that u need to take into account.